# JFX 13 Chart Update is Not Smooth (Snaps on Transition)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm reading live EEG data off of a portable EEG scanner and graphing it using a StackedAreaChart. This is running on a Windows 10 (Latest Update) computer using Java 13u2, and JFX 13.

The EEG sends data every second which is updated on the graph. The way I do this is just by adding the data to the end of the chart (For the first 20 entries) then after 20 entries, I delete the zeroith entry, and subtract 1 from all the x values in the series (This is a time series on the X axis, so this makes sense).

However, the transition seen on screen is pretty rough. Nodes on the graph seemingly wander around before attaching themselves to the correct position, and the result is... lackluster...[EEG Graph Issue](https://youtu.be/F5GbNloqUfg)

Here is the update subroutine (This runs every second in a loop):

```
                        var eSenseData = eSenseChart.getData();
                        var brainwaveData = brainwaveChart.getData();
                        //If there are no series, add empty ones
                        if (eSenseData.isEmpty()) {
                            eSenseData.add(attention);
                            eSenseData.add(meditation);
                            //data.add(mentalEffort);
                            //data.add(familiarity);

                            brainwaveData.add(delta);
                            brainwaveData.add(theta);
                            brainwaveData.add(lowAlpha);
                            brainwaveData.add(highAlpha);
                            brainwaveData.add(lowBeta);
                            brainwaveData.add(highBeta);
                            brainwaveData.add(lowGamma);
                            brainwaveData.add(highGamma);
                        }
                        //Get Old Data, take most recent 20 entries and graph them
                        var acceptableEntries = 20;
                        //If the number of entries is less than acceptableEntries
                        if (eSenseData.get(0).getData().size() < acceptableEntries) {
                            eSenseData.get(0).getData().add(new Data<>(eSenseData.get(0).getData().size(), packet.getAttention()));
                            eSenseData.get(1).getData().add(new Data<>(eSenseData.get(1).getData().size(), packet.getMeditation()));
}
else {
                            setNew(eSenseData.get(0), new Data<>(20, packet.getAttention()));
                            setNew(eSenseData.get(1), new Data<>(20, packet.getMeditation()));
}

/**
     * Removes the first entry and adds the new one.
     *
     * @param series The series to use
     * @param value The value to add
     */
    private static <X, Y> void setNew(Series<Integer, Y> series, Data<Integer, Y> value) {
        series.getData().remove(0);
        series.getData().stream().forEach(data -> {
            data.setXValue(data.getXValue() - 1);
        });
        series.getData().add(value);
    }
```

NOTE: This "snapping" effect also happens when the chart is being created, but to a lesser extent.

How would I resolve this to make the transition smoother?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra Given that the server produces live values and I can't copy the hardware that produces it, I think that would be quite the bit of work... but I can do it. I'll just need a bit of time.

Comment: mock the data feed ...